# What is the replacement for pipe to :error in Elixir?

Tags: unit-testing, elixir

I am trying to upgrade my library's tests. Initially the tests were based on Amrita. The following code is one of the test and since Amrita has not been upgraded since last year I decided to migrate my tests to use the default test framework instead. I changed the code from:

```
    fact "Test symlink: For non existent src file" do

      src = Path.join(fixture_path, "testdir3xx")

      try do
        @dest |> ! path_exists
        symlink(src, @dest)
        F.read_link(@dest) |> {:error, :enoent}
        @dest |> ! path_exists
      after
        File.rm_rf @dest
      end
end
```

to this:

```
defmodule TestSymlinkFornonexistent do

  src = Path.join(fixture_path, "testdir3xx")
  try do
    @dest |> File.exists? |> refute 
    symlink(src, @dest)
    F.read_link(@dest) |> {:error, :enoent}
    @dest |> ! path_exists
  after
    File.rm_rf @dest
  end  
end
```

When run it using `MIX_ENV=test mix test --trace`, the error that I get is the following.

```
** (ArgumentError) cannot pipe F.read_link(@dest) into {:error, :enoent}, can only pipe into local calls foo(), remote calls Foo.bar() or anonymous functions calls foo.()
```

Don't really understand the error or the form that it should be in. Can someone help ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but was it ever working? It's the first time I see something like this. What's it even supposed to do?

Comment: What's wrong with a simple pattern match? `{:error, :enoent} = F.read_link(@dest)`

Comment: I am using Amrita so the `|>` also asserts that it's equal to `{:error, :enoent}`

Comment: What do you mean by `deprecated`? Do you have any warnings or errors?

Comment: This is the error `** (ArgumentError) cannot pipe F.read_link(@dest) into {:error, :enoent}, can only pipe into local calls foo(), remote calls Foo.bar() or anonymous functions calls foo.()
`

Comment: `elixir` 1.3 is not supported: https://github.com/josephwilk/amrita/issues/124

Comment: Sorry that my question lacks clarity. I have updated to make it more clear what I am trying to achieve.